# Oracle hstore module

Tags: oracle, database-design

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/hstore.html

Is an Oracle (Database) module available like (PostgreSQL) hstore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such thing available for Oracle.

The only thing that might possibly get close to that feature is to use a XML column that simply stores key/value pairs, something like:

```
<data>
   <entry key="key_1">value_1</entry>
   <entry key="key_2">value_2</entry>
   <entry key="key_3">value_3</entry>
</data>
```

But it isn't as efficient as PostgreSQL's hstore and indexing is a lot more complicated